# MySQL SELECT with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, where-clause

When searching for available cars, I'm trying to `SELECT` from cars table `WHERE` the IDs do not include the already booked cars.
For that, I used :

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cars 
WHERE id NOT IN (" . implode(',', $bookedCarIds) . ") 
AND (location = '$fromlocation'  AND fromdate BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate') 
"); 

$result->execute();
$availableCars = [];
$availableCars = $result->fetchAll();
```

Which works perfectly fine. 
 
However, the issue arises when there are no already booked cars in the selected location and dates (where `$bookedCarsIds` is *NULL*). To deal with this issue, I used the following code, which throws a syntax error.

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cars 
WHERE id NOT IN (" . implode(',', $bookedCarIds) . ") AND 
(location = '$fromlocation'  AND fromdate BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate') 
OR WHERE location = '$fromlocation'  AND fromdate BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate'
");

 $result->execute();
 $availableCars = [];
 $availableCars = $result->fetchAll();
```

How can I solve this issue by making changes in this MySQL query alone, without altering the rest of my code?

Thank you.

Comment: what type of error is thrown,you have to state that

Comment: Error : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND (location =..

Comment: before your prepare statement add line like ```array_push($bookedCarId, -1);```

Comment: Somewhat related: [Delete rows via PDO query using PHP arrays with NOT IN with row constructor expression and an IN condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71794983/2943403)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `PDO`, you need to create a dynamic `WHERE` clause with parameters like in this example:

```
$whereClause = [];
$params = [];
if (!empty($bookedCarIds)) {
    $whereClause[] = 'id NOT IN (?' . str_repeat(', ?', count($bookedCarIds) - 1) . ')';
    $params = $bookedCarIds;
}
if (!empty($fromlocation)) {
    $whereClause[] = 'location = ?';
    $params[] = $fromlocation;
}
if (!empty($fromdate) && !empty($todate)) {
    $whereClause[] = 'fromdate BETWEEN ? AND ?';
    $params[] = $fromdate;
    $params[] = $todate;
}
$whereClause = !empty($whereClause) ? 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $whereClause) : '';

$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cars $whereClause");
$result->execute($params);
$availableCars = $result->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I'll upvote for him, as although the question is a duplicate, we need more good examples on Stack Overflow, as opposed to a Pacific Ocean of very bad code that stays here for ages.